# Jquery SELECT2 is not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, jquery-select2

This is my index file.

```
<?php
    use yii\helpers\Url;
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
    use kartik\grid\GridView;
    use johnitvn\ajaxcrud\CrudAsset; 
    use johnitvn\ajaxcrud\BulkButtonWidget;

    CrudAsset::register($this);
    $this->registerJs($this->render('script2.js'), \yii\web\VIEW::POS_READY);
    ?>
    <div class="op-transaction-listing-index">
        <div id="ajaxCrudDatatable">
            <?=GridView::widget([
                'id'=>'crud-datatable2',
                'dataProvider' => $listing,
                //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                'pjax'=>true,
                'columns' => require(__DIR__.'/_columns.php'),
                'toolbar'=> [

                ],          
                'striped' => true,
                'condensed' => true,
                'responsive' => true,    
                'resizableColumns'=>true,
                'persistResize'=>true,
                'bordered'=> true,      
                'panel' => [
                    'type' => 'primary', 
                    'heading' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Op Transaction Listings listing',

            ])?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?=  Html::a('Create',false,['id'=>'test','class'=>'btn btn-success pull-right'])?>

    <?php Modal::begin([
        "id"=>"ajaxCrudModal",
        "footer"=>"",// always need it for jquery plugin
    ])?>
    <?php Modal::end(); ?>
```

What I do is click on the table cell it will remove the text within and append a select2 dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#crud-datatable2-container > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)').on('click',function(){
        $(this).text('');
        $(this).append('<select name="testing" class="form-control" id="testing"></select>');

        $('select#testing').select2();
    });
});
```

But then it keep showing `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function..`this type of error. I have only 1 script inside. Where did I did wrong?

Comment: Have you included the select2 plugin? Look here: https://github.com/select2/select2/releases

Comment: @freshmouse yes, its included already

Comment: Post the html source of head tag, where you put these scripts references.

Comment: But when I use another script (let say A) that have select2 function it works. But then when I change to use script(B) it will show the error